# How to create arrays for Highchart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to create some arrays for high charts. I have watched the is railcasts episode about how to create a highchart. http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts

Here is my some of my Highchart JavaScript code
:

```
  series: [

  {
    name: "Indtjening",
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 1.day.ago.to_i * 1000%>,
    data: <%= Reklamer.sum(:earn, :order => :dato , :group => :dato).values %>
  },
   {
    name: "Iqmedier",
    color: '#DBD200',
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 1.day.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
    data: <%= Reklamer.where(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier').all.map(&:earn) %>
  }
  ,
   {
    name: "Euroads",
    color: '#1B7B94',
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day.to_i * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 1.day.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
    data: <%= Reklamer.where(:virksomhed => 'Euroads').all.map(&:earn) %>
  }]
```

My table:

```
id  virksomhed  dato                   earn     
10  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     0   
11  Euroads     2011-02-01 00:07:24     144   
15  Iqmedier    2011-02-15 00:00:00     5
```

My chart - as you can see Iqmedier has the wrong date (17. February) and all the other bars do also have the wrong date.
![My chart][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1MIN.png

Indtjening should take the sum of Iqmedier and Euroads and start from the last date in the column dato.

How do find the last date in the dato and create it to an integer?

Comment: You could answer you own question to show your solution that way the rest of us can learn as well and your question won't stay unaswered.

Comment: I did not find a solution instead I chossed to make a simple table.

Comment: What is the javascript as rendered on the page? We need to see what the resulting data looks like for the series.

Answer (score 0):

To convert these date to HighCharts you have to do this:

```
dato.utc.to_i*1000
```

This should resolve your problem with datas.

Note that you have to multiply (* 1000) to get the milliseconds "format".